# Ошибка при присвоение переменной string из класса label'у?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня есть класс System Block который агрегирует 2 класса: Mouse и Monitor. Все эти классы наследники базового класса: Computer, в котором есть переменная: name_of_module и метод который вызывает эту переменную. Данной функцией я получаю доступ к имени мыши(которая подключена к системному блоку):

```
    string System_Block::getMouseName()
{
    return Mous.get_name();
}
```

Далее, я пытаюсь присвоить данное значение Label5 из Windows Form:

```
std::string namem = Comps[number_of_SB].getMouseName();
        label2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(number_of_SB+1);
        label5->Text = namem;//Здесь ошибка, подсвечивается label5
```

Но появляется ошибка:

> function "System::Windows::Forms::Label::Text::set" cannot be called
>   with the given argument list

В чём проблема?

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @Unick Тупанул, исправил.

Comment: ```label5->Text = namem``` - должно быть, в этой. Тип ```label5->Text``` наверное ```String^``` ? А Вы пытаетесь проинициализировать переменной ```типа std::string```.

Comment: @isnullxbh Если я делаю через `System::Convert::ToString()` то вылазит уже другая ошибка: **no instance of overloaded function "System::Convert::ToString" matches the argument list**

Comment: Я Вам про другую строчку кода говорю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
label5->Text = gcnew System::String(namem.c_str());
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!)

Comment: @nait123321: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
label5->Text = String(namem.c_str());
```

Comment: С `c_str()` пробовал, но он вообще не видит такую функцию.

Comment: @nait123321, не обманывайте, Вы работаете с классом std::string, а c_str() - метод этого класса. Так что если у Вас и не сработал мой пример, то не из-за этого.

Comment: @nait123321, скорее всего ошибка в том, что нужно действительно использовать оператор ```gcnew```.